# Entity Framework 4.1: saving many to many relationship saves exsting child entities again in the db

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a very frustrating problem (for me anyway):

I have a simple scenario where I have a Product entity and a CombinedProduct Entity. There is a many to many relationship between them, so a Product can belong to multiple CombinedProducts and a CombinedProduct can contain many products.

I first create a product and save this to the database. Later on I create a CombinedProduct and add this product. When I try to save this CombinedProduct, the product entity is added again to the database by Entity Framework instead of just adding a relationship... This is really driving me nuts.

I already tried to attach the product again to the context before saving, but Entity complains that it already has a product with the same key...

Below you find the code for all of this (simplified and code stripped):

**Product Entity**

```
Public Class SingleProduct
  Property SingleProductId As Integer
  Property CombinedProducts As ICollection(Of CombinedProduct)
End Class
```

**CombinedProduct**

```
Public Class CombinedProduct
  Public Sub New()
    Me.Products = New HashSet(Of SingleProduct)()
  End Sub

  Property CombinedProductId As Integer
  Property Products As ICollection(Of SingleProduct)
End Class
```

**Many to Many Relastionship definition**

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
   modelBuilder.Entity(Of CombinedProduct)().
                        HasMany(Function(c) c.Products).
                        WithMany(Function(p) p.CombinedProducts).
                        Map(Sub(m)
                                m.ToTable("CombinedProductSingleProducts")
                                m.MapLeftKey("SingleProductId")
                                m.MapRightKey("CombinedProductId")
                            End Sub)
End Sub
```

**Code used for saving**

```
Using myDataContext As New DataContext
  myDataContext.CombinedProducts.Add(product)
  myDataContext.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

**Already tried attaching before saving but that didn't work**

```
For Each prd In product.Products
   If myDataContext.Entry(prd).State = EntityState.Detached Then
      myDataContext.SingleProducts.Attach(prd)
   End If
Next
```

One "solution" I found was right before saving, clearing the products list and getting the products again from the database and add those to the CombinedProduct, but that can hardly be the solution.

Hope someone can help me, this is driving me nuts!
(I use Entity Framework 4.1, with Code First)

**Edit**

**Adding the product**: This is done in it's own datacontext at some other form:

```
Using myDataContext As New DataContext
    myDataContext.SingleProducts.Add(singleProduct)
    myDataContext.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

**The combined product creation**:

```
Dim myCombinedProduct = New CombinedProduct
myCombinedProduct.Products.Add(product)
```

The product I add is first fetched again in it's own datacontext:

```
Using myDataContext As New DataContext
    Return myDataContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.ProductId = id)
End Using
```

**Edit**

The full story in the hopes of being more clear:

I have a winforms application with two forms: one for managing products and one for managing combined products. The application is N-Tier (User layer, business layer and data layer).

On the form for managing you products you can simply add/update/delete products. On this form everything works fine.

The combined product form is another matter:

1. when loading the form I retrieve all products from the database, going through the business and datalayer. The function to retrieve the products in the datalayer has it's own DataContext (using block). This function returns an iEnumerable of Products.
2. The retrieved products are added to a number of comboboxes as objects.
3. You select the products you want to add to the combined product by selecting them
4. when saving I create a new CombinedProduct entity in the user layer, retrieve the product objects from the comboboxes and add them to the new CombinedProduct Object
5. I send the CombinedProduct object to the business layer where I perform a number of business rules
6. If all is well, the combinedProduct is send to the datalayer, where I **try** to save it again in it's own datacontext (using-block).

So I have multiple DataContexts as they live and die in the datalayer.

Hope this makes things a bit more clear.

Comment: *"I first create a product and save this to the database. Later on I create a CombinedProduct and add this product."* Can you show the code for this procedure? This is the really important code snippet.

Comment: **Adding the product** 
This is done in it's own datacontext at some other form 
`Using myDataContext As New DataContext
   myDataContext.SingleProducts.Add(singleProduct)
   myDataContext.SaveChanges()
End Using`

**The combined product creation**
`Dim myCombinedProduct = New CombinedProduct
myCombinedProduct.Products.Add(product) `

The product I add is first fetched again in it's own datacontext
`
 Using myDataContext As New DataContext
   Return myDataContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.ProductId = id)
End Using
`

Comment: You can edit your question for such details ("edit" link below question). I've already done it now, just as info for the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF all entities that you are trying to relate must belong to the same datacontext,other wise it would not recognize your product as an existing one, and would add a new one instead
in your first usings,  your product must be fetched from db first.

I never had to attatch/detach entities, but i have seen most people run into issues doing that.

Also in many to many, both entities have to be added to the context, relationship is just going to fill the join table

looking at the discussion it looks like you have a repository for each entity type, and are getting objects through those repository methods. If thats the case, then IMO this design has a problem, since object relationships are stored in a common context.In your case all these repositories should have the same dbcontexts. You might think that going to the database has some performance issues, but you are going to the db even when you attach.

Comment: I was afraid of something like this. How should I accomplish using just one Datacontext in a winforms applications? Should I create a datacontext at application startup and simply keep using that one, or is that a bad idea?

Comment: long running datacontexts are not really recommended. One option could be to get your product in the dataContext again ( you already have the key for the product) and keep your dataContexts scope limited, like whenever you want to contact db, just open one context, fetch the products you need, modify their values, save and dispose dbcontext.

Comment: But that seems really strange to me? I have to first get the products again from the database, when the context already knowns them (I think anyway, because when I try to attach them, EF says it can't attach them because a product with the same key is already in the context)

Comment: but I think that would mean on DataContext for the entire time of the Winform life, right? I have been trying to find some documentation or blogs if this an acceptable solution or what the consequences would be, but no luck so far...

Comment: well like every, it depends, i would keep it short, i would create a context from the form, create repositories that i need with in the usings and dispose the datacontex. see if this post helps any http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2008/02/17/context-lifetimes-dispose-or-reuse.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the late response I have been really really busy (no excuse really). I have rewritten my app, so that I now have one DataContext (Singleton). It works great now, no problems so far. The only issue I have now is that Entity Framework, leaked into other layers than the datalayer of my application. Feels wrong somehow, but for now this will do.  Thx again for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly in which order you are doing which steps but the right order should be:

If everything happens in one context:

```
Using myDataContext As New DataContext
    Dim product = myDataContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.ProductId = id)

    Dim myCombinedProduct = New CombinedProduct
    myCombinedProduct.Products.Add(product)

    myDataContext.CombinedProducts.Add(myCombinedProduct)
End Using
```

Loading the `product` attaches to the context and avoids the duplication. It must happen *before* you add `myCombinedProduct` to the context.

If you load the `product` in another context:

```
Using myDataContext As New DataContext
    myDataContext.Products.Attach(product)

    Dim myCombinedProduct = New CombinedProduct
    myCombinedProduct.Products.Add(product)

    myDataContext.CombinedProducts.Add(myCombinedProduct)
End Using
```

You have to attach the `product` to the new context, again *before* you add `myCombinedProduct` to the context.

**Edit**

If your new `myCombinedProduct` *including the product collection* comes into the datalayer in a *detached* state the following should work:

```
Using myDataContext As New DataContext
    For Each prd In myCombinedProduct.Products
        myDataContext.SingleProducts.Attach(prd)
    Next

    myDataContext.CombinedProducts.Add(myCombinedProduct)
End Using
```

Comment: Hmmm, that is were I am going wrong I think. In my solution (which is N-Tier) I try to attach the products after adding them to combinedproduct. Every function in my datalayer has a new datacontext, as most actions of adding products is done in the business layer where I don't have a context. So I see two solutions: rework everything and just pass product id's to the datalayer with the combinedproduct object and fetch/add the products there, or use one datacontext for the entire winforms application, but that doesn't seem right at all. I am hoping for a third solution...

Comment: @DirkDooms: Attaching after you have added the product to the collection in `myCombinedProduct` is not the problem, only attaching after you have added to the context (the last line in my examples). I'm still unclear what you are exactly doing in which context and in which order. Can you try to edit your question and make it as clear as possible?

Comment: @Slaumu: I edited by post in the hope of being more clear. Thx for your time and help so far!!